# Vue router - How to open in new tab in production?

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, vue-router, dev-to-production, postgrest

I am using Vue, Vuetify and my database is in postgreSQL with an API-backend from postgREST (https://postgrest.org/en/stable/). When using the localhost and hash mode everything is fine locally. I can open the component product in a new tab when using this syntax:

```
const route = this.$router.resolve({ path: `/product/${value.id}` }) (1)
window.open(route.href, '_blank')                                    (2)
```

However, in the production environment with postgREST-server when opening in a new tab, I get the wrong url :

```
http:server_name/api/#/product/1                                     (3)
```

When I remove ***/api*** from the above url (3) and rewrite it like this :

```
http:server_name/#/product                                           (4)
```

I get the correct page. 
Is it a possible **nginx** rule that can be written to make sure that
***http:server_name/api/#/product/1***  is automatically rewritten to the correct url ***http:server_name/#/product***? or How can I change **vue-router** or vue config file in order to get same behavior in production as in locahost ?

Comment: this sounds like an nginx/apache conf issue

Answer (score 0):

A possible client-side workaround is to strip the `/api` prefix in production mode:

```js
const url = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? route.href.replace('/api', '')
            : route.href
window.open(url, '_blank')
```